# How to change Deform Default validation fail error message?

Tags: python, web-deployment, pyramid, deform, colander

I need to change the deform validation error message

```
'There was a problem with your submission Errors have been highlighted below'.
```

How can I customize my own error message or hide this error message?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read the [colander documentation](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/colander/en/latest/api.html#colander.Invalid.msg)? Have you checked StackOverflow for similar questions? Have you checked the [deformdemo for similar situations](http://demo.substanced.net/deformdemo/interfield)? StackOverflow members expect that the developer show some effort to find an answer before posting a question.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion  . I already read 'colander Documentation' and see all example 'deform-demo for similar'. and create  a new error message for new custom validation  and use for my input field so my question is still valid how to default validation  error message ''There was a problem with your submission Errors have been highlighted below'. customize  or Hide

Answer (score 0):

You can [override any Chameleon template that Deform uses](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/deform/en/latest/templates.html#overriding-the-default-templates).

To determine which template to override, search the Deform package source code for the string you want to modify, in this case, "There was a problem with your submission". You will find `templates/form.pt`.

Create a directory in your package's root, say `templates/_deform/`, to hold your template overrides.

In your Pyramid application, specify where you store your template overrides. Then in your application's `__init__.py`:

```
from deform.renderer import configure_zpt_renderer

# other stuff

def main(global_config, **settings):

    # configuration stuff

    configure_zpt_renderer(["mypackage:templates/_deform"])
```

Finally copy the template `form.pt` from the Deform package to the overrides folder that you created. This template will override the Deform default. Edit its strings as needed.

If you use [internationalization](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/deform/en/latest/i18n.html), you should instead edit the language's translation file, instead of following the above procedure.